# Magento 2: how override translates in language pack?

Tags: magento2, language-package

I installed language pack in `**app/i18n/magento2translations/language_nl_nl/**` with file **nl_NL.csv** It's works perfect.
Also, I added in custom theme file **`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/nl_NL.csv`** with my custom translates, but it's not working for me (mode: developer, static content and caches were cleaned).
When I move custom translates to language pack's **nl_NL.csv** custom translates works fine.
I think the language pack has more priority as a custom theme **i18n translates**.
How override translates in language pack in the correct way?